# Twitter API users/search order by followers count

Tags: php, json, twitter

Using the following call to twitter's API, I can return a list of twitter accounts with a search parameter (e.g. '#farming').

```
$url_search = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json";
              $getfield_search = "?q=%23farming";
              $twitter_search = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
              $searchstring = json_decode($twitter_search->setGetfield($getfield_search)
              ->buildOauth($url_search, $requestMethod)
              ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
```

However, the results appear to be in no order. Is there a way to order the results by `[followers_count]` or if not, does anyone know what the default ordering is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to sort by followers count . try this following code

```
$json = "< YOUR TWITTER JSON RESULT RESPONSE >";
$result = json_decode($json, true);

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['followers_count'] - $b['followers_count'];// asc
    // return $b['followers_count'] - $a['followers_count'];// desc
}

usort($result, 'sortByOrder');

echo '<pre>'.print_r($result,true).'</pre>'; //ordered array
```

You can choose to use ASC or DESC order.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only sorts the current requested page order. i.e. page=2 will return a new set of results with follower count higher than the last of page=1